# How to get visitor data from Google Analytics, and show them in a public map?

Tags: dictionary, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, onmouseover

I have a project for getting the data from google analytics, from where the visitors are coming. This is an example: http://www.avaaz.org/en/community.php

On mouse over in a country, then show how much visitors does it have.
Which is better to use Javascript with PHP or something else.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Export data to Google spreadsheet and follow the spreadsheet mapper tutorial: http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/spreadsheet3.html. All in all the question seems rather broad and should be broken up into multiple questions (at least 2, how do I get data from GA, how do I present data on a map).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this though the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/).  If its your own data then I recommend you use php and go with a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  There is a tutorial here on how to get started with the Google analytics api.  [Tutorial Hello analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api)

I haven't tried it yet, but they recently added some info on merging Google charts with Google analytics data.  There is a map in Google charts so this should be possible.  You can read about it here [Visualizing Google Analytics Data with Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts)